# jQuery function not work for Second Time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I write this jQuery after it works fine completely for first time it give this error then for second time none of function work.I also use jQuery UI you can see in code.

This error happens after first time complete:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } jquery-1.8.3.js:564

Markup and code:

```
<link href="../../StyleSheets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(":checkbox").change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                $this.closest("tr").addClass("SlectedtRow");
            } else {
                $this.closest("tr").removeClass("SlectedtRow");
            }
        })
        var tittle = '';
        var url = '';
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "بلی",
                    click: function () {
                        DoAction();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "خیر",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        // Link to open the dialog
        $('#ConfirmRiver , #DeleteRiver').click(function (event) {

            var IsSelected = false;
            var ModalText = "  آیا رودخانه ";
            $('#RiverForm input:checked').each(function () {
                ModalText += this.value + " - "
                IsSelected = true;
            });

            if (IsSelected) {
                document.getElementById('ErrorContent').style.display = "none";
                ModalText = ModalText.slice(0, -2);
                if (this.id == 'DeleteRiver') {
                    ModalText += "حذف گردد" + "؟"
                    tittle = 'حذف رودخانه'
                    url = '@Url.Action("DeleteRiver", "WaterResourcesManagement")';
                }
                if (this.id == 'ConfirmRiver') {
                    ModalText += "تایید نهایی گردد" + "؟"
                    tittle = 'تایید اصلاح و بازبینی رودخانه '
                    url = '@Url.Action("ChangeRiverARStatus", "WaterResourcesManagement")';
                }
                $('#ModalMessgae').text(ModalText);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                $("#dialog").dialog({ title: tittle });
                event.preventDefault();

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('ErrorContent').innerHTML = " اطلاعات مورد نظر را انتخاب نمایید";
                document.getElementById('ErrorContent').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('ErrorContent').className = "msg-Yellow";
            }
        })
        function DoAction() {
            var list = [];
            $('#RiverForm input:checked').each(function () {
                if( url == '@Url.Action("ChangeRiverARStatus", "WaterResourcesManagement")')
                {
                    var Ar= $('#RiverForm').find("input[value='"+this.id+"']").attr('id');
                    list.push(Ar);
                }
                else{
                    list.push(this.id);}
            });
            var parameters = {};
            parameters = JSON.stringify({ "Id": list, AreaID: @Request.QueryString["AreaID"] });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "html",
                traditional: true,
                data: parameters,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#updateAjax').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $('#updateAjax').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first time" and "second time"? The code shown defines several event handlers, so are you talking about the first time a checkbox changes, the first time the click handler runs, or...?

Comment: need help... provide jsfiddle

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "html",` what is it exactly `json` or `html`

Comment: Yes For First I check checkbox and click handle and ajax happen success works fine then it give error that i said.for second time none of event work.

Comment: @Jai - isn't `contentType` applicable to the request and `dataType` applicable to the expected response? No reason why they can't be different: notice what the success handler does with the result...

Comment: I use this for another page and it works fine.it give success message in my element.and page refresh succefully.the problem is with after that that give error message and second time that doesnt work.Is need to add my html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add if (!request.isjax()) in all jquery code and it works